# Error solving third order ODE in version 10. No error in V9. DSolve`DSolveKovacicDump`

Tags: differential-equations, version-10

This is an ode which is solved with no error in V9, but gives a very strange error in V10. Is this a regression bug?

On version 9, the ode is solved with no error

```
  $Version
  (* 9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013) *)
  ClearAll[x, y]
  ode = ((30 + 4 x)y[x]+5(-6 + x)x y'[x] +x^2(3 + x) y''[x]+ x^3 y'''[x] == 0);
  DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now on version 10

```
 $Version
 (*10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)*)
 ClearAll[x, y];
 ode = ((30 + 4 x) y[x] +5(-6 + x) x y'[x] +x^2 (3 + x)y''[x]+x^3 y'''[x] == 0);
 DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

I get screen full of errors

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At the bottom I see the same solution as given by Version 9 !

This happens after I restart the kernel, on fresh session. The computation takes few minutes (on my PC it took 5 minutes, old PC). Reproducible.

I am on windows 7, 64 bit. Can other reproduce this? Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: I get error messages **both** in v9 as in v10. You may have redirected your messages in V9 to the Messages screen. Looks like a case for support@wolfram.com.